# Can I use a perfume sprayer to spray bleach solution?

Tags: cleaning, spraying

I am looking for a way to spray a moderate bleach solution up under the rim of my toilet. One idea I had was to use a "perfume sprayer"-type thing with the bulb that you squeeze. Would this work? Would the flow rate be too low? Would the bleach damage the sprayer? Are there better alternatives I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a squeeze bottle with a neck shaped like swans (or some sort of waterfowl)?

Or a solid bleach block that you put in the tank?

Comment: thanks, this is a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

Bleach will likely make spring rust and it will quickly fail. Even regular sprayers don't last long. However, there are chemically rated spray bottles that will last and stand up to chlorine. That's what I used for just what you are planning, works great!

I got my sprayer at Home Depot. Here is a [set on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00ABYVT64) for reference

[image]

Comment: thanks, this is a great answer!